# Material ui: how to `makeStyles` with duplicate key?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this style

```
    background:
      "-moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.88) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 66%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)",
    background:
      "-webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.88) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 66%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)",
    background:
      "linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.88) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 66%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)",
```

After create style with `makeStyles`, React complains about `Duplicate key 'background'`.

Is there a proper way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`material-ui` does apply the *vendor-prefixes* automatically. According to the docs:

> JSS uses feature detection to apply the correct prefixes. Don't be surprised if you can't see a specific prefix in the latest version of Chrome. Your browser probably doesn't need it.

Just keep only the last key in the object:

```
background: "linear-gradient..."
```

https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-prefixes